# Constructing two independent random variables from two given random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose I have two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ with a joint exponential pdf, say
$$
f(x_1,x_2)=abK\cdot \exp\left\{-(ax_1+bx_2+cx_1 x_2 )\right\},
$$
for $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$, and for some $a,b,c>0$, and $K$ is a normalizing constant.

I want to construct a random vector $Y=(Y_1,Y_2)^T$ by some transformation
$$
Y=AX,\text{ where }X=(X_1,X_2)^T,
$$
such that $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are now independent, (but not necessarily exponential).

What should  be the components of (the square matrix) $A$ here, if this is possible?

Can anyone also recommend an article or a book that might have discussed my problem or anything similar to this?

Comment: First thought: how to fix that in the extreme case $X_1=X_2$?

Comment: Let's not consider such case here.

Comment: As you wish, but keep in mind that extreme cases can be very predictive in matters like this.

Comment: @drhab How about $Y_1=X_1$ and $Y_2=X_1-X_2=0$? Those are independent, and carry the same information as $X_1, X_2$.

Comment: @Arthur That is indeed an (extreme) solution. If acceptable for the OP then in the general case we can go for $(Y_1,Y_2)=(f(X_1,X_2),g(X_1,X_2))$ where $f$ is some suitable function and $g$ is a constant function.

Comment: @drhab Although if we want the $Y_i$ to have (roughly) the same domain as the $X_i$, and we want $f,g$ to be suitably nice (say, continuous) it won't always work.

Comment: Yes @drhab, I want something like what you said: $Y_i = f_i(X_1, X_2)$ for some suitable functions $f_i$.

Comment: As stated, you can let $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ be *any* independent random variables. What relationship do you require $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ to have to $X_1$ and $X_2$?

Comment: An appropriate restriction is for the $Y_i$ to be defined on the same probability space as the $X_i$. The question becomes: if a space is sufficiently rich to support a jointly exponential pair of variables, is it always rich enough to support a pair of independent variables? By the way, what does it mean for a random vector of $\mathbb R^2$ to be exponentially distributed?

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need two variables.

First, transform $X_1$ to uniform distribution on $[0; 1]$ via some function $f$. Now let $\gamma: [0; 1] \to [0; 1]^2$ be Hilbert version of Peano curve, and $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ been it's $x$ and $y$ coordinates. Then $Y_1 = \gamma_1(f(X_1))$ and $Y_2 = \gamma_2(f(X_1))$ are independent (see "Stochastic Independence and Space-Filling Curves" by John A. R. Holbrook for proof; the main idea is that probability of getting into any square with side $2^{-k}$ and angle with coordinates $(n \cdot 2^{-k}, m\cdot 2^{-k})$ is $4^{-k}$ starting from the $k$-th iteration).

Comment: This seems a bit overkill. If $U$ is a uniform random variable on $[0, 1]$, the bits of the binary expansion of $U$ are an i.i.d. sequence of Bernouilli RVs, so the first and the second bits suffice to answer OP's question.